# How to reset a deck of cards?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a game with a deck of cards. Currently, I only have one class with a LinkedList of cards that I added individually with the add method. I have the rest of my game coded except for at a certain point, I want to reset the deck of cards back to a full set like when the program first started executing. How would I go about doing this in the easiest way? I would like to keep it in a LinkedList structure because I can use the built in shuffle method, etc...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
LinkedList<String> deck = new LinkedList<String>();
deck.add("2C");
deck.add("3C");
deck.add("4C");
deck.add("5C");
    ... //etc
Collections.shuffle(deck);
System.out.println("Shuffled deck: \n" + deck);
```

(I want to reset 'deck' back to the initial state after altering the deck (remove, deal, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and by far cheapest way is to use a *fresh* set of cards.

Generate a sorted deck once, and *before changing it*, make a "working copy". Or just create a new one from scratch by putting that code into a method `LinkedList<String> newDeck()`!

This is *very* simple and clean:

```
LinkedList<String> workingdeck = new LinkedList<String>(masterdeck);
```

If you want to be very OOP, make a class that manages the deck. Still: to reset, you might want to just create a new deck; either by copying or by cloning.

Comment: Why bother keeping one around? Just make a new one when you need it and discard the old.

Comment: @Bill: granted, but he probably isn't that used to writing own methods yet. The copy code is sometimes even simpler for beginners. Note that he is still in `main`.

Comment: I disagree. If that copy gets modified then the program will suddenly start behaving differently and that would be harder to debug.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: I do have many methods. The methods are for the different gameplay tests and actions. I have a decent knowledge of Java, I am just not looking for a super complex solution.

Comment: As I asked Code-Guru, could you please provide a sample implementation?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Sorry I forgot to tag you to notify you. Could you please provide a sample implementation?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks for your help. I actually had a revelation and created a method to reset the deck by using the built in clear method, followed by adding all the cards in again. It returns a LinkedList so I can still shuffle it after I reset it.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, as you can see, he does not get the idea why he should be returning new / copied instanstance. So, can you explain?

Comment: @lord_sneed A sample implementation was in my post from the very beginnning. But the longer I think of it, I have to agree with @Bill - using an **entirely fresh deck** is by far the best solution. No issues if anyone messes with the master deck, no multi threading issues. `clear()` and then adds again is probably the worst variant you can do.

Answer (score 2):

The most object-oriented solution to this problem is to create a `Deck` class. Then initialize the `LinkedList` of cards inside the constructor. To "reset" your deck of cards, you simply create a new `Deck` object.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it a little with a sample implementation (with creating a new instance from the gameplay class)? I am familiar with the built in methods, but I am a little rusty with creating new instances from classes, etc.

Comment: Start by writing the `Deck` class. You already know how to create an instance because you created one from the `LinkedList` class. Using a custom class that you wrote is exactly the same as using the any class from the standard API.

Comment: import java.util.*;

public class Deck {
 private LinkedList<String> deck = new LinkedList<String>();

 public Deck(LinkedList deck) {
  this.deck = deck;
 }
 
 public LinkedList createDeck(LinkedList deck) {
   deck.add("2C");
   deck.add("3C");

Comment: I get an error with that: "error: Class names, 'Deck', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested" but...

Comment: Please post a new question with your code since this is a new issue.

Comment: In the mean time, I will say that it looks like you are on the right track. I suggest that you remove the `createDeck()` method since that is what the constructor is for. Also, the constructor doesn't need a parameter since you already initialize the `deck` variable with a new `LinkedList`.

Comment: If you would rather edit your original question, that is fine, too. You just need to do *something* to make your code more readable than it is in a comment.

Comment: Ok so I got rid of it and added all the deck.add statements inside the constructor. Is that correct? Then to create a new instance of the deck in the game class I just do:

Comment: that will go in `main()` or wherever you want to create a new Deck object, yes.

Comment: I still want to use the built in shuffle method on the LinkedList also.

Comment: Please post a new quesiton and describe in detail what you have done so far and what exactly isn't working the way you want it to.